# Custom type or action on default argument with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to convert arguments I pass to argparse in an other format; the idea is to pass a number (a float typically) and to convert it in a string (Fortran notation for a float, typically).

First, I tried to create a custom type

```
def FortranFloat(value):
    vfloat = float(value)
    vfloat = str(vfloat) + "d0"
    return vfloat

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--xmin=", dest="xmin", type=FortranFloat, default=-2.0)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

It works well... if I actually give the `--xmin=` argument. Else, it just keeps the `-2.0`, without converting it in `-2.0d0` as I wish. I therefore thought that it could be easier to give the default value the format I want, so replacing `2.0` by `'2.0d0'`... The interesting thing is that it is evaluated, because it crashes and raise the following error

```
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --xmin=: invalid FortranFloat value: '-2.0d0'
```

To get around this problem I tried to create a custom action

```
class FortranConverter(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_strings=None):
        if type(values) is float:
            values = str(values) + "d0"
            setattr(args, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--xmin=", dest="xmin", type=float, default=-2.0, action=FortranConverter)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

That didn't work either. It doesn't even seem to go through my action (if I print something in the `__call__`, it will just ignore it).

Any thought, idea or explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `default` is a string, it is passed through the `type` function.  Anything else is used as is: `setattr(namespace, dest, default)`.  Have you tried '-2.0'?  Your `FortranFloat` should convert that to '-2.0d0'.

Another option is to modify your `FortranFloat` so it recognizes a string with 'd0', and passes it through unchanged.

The argument string is passed through `type` before it is passed to the `action`.  And if I recall the code correctly, a `default` never goes through the `action`; it is set directly.

You don't need it, but to work, your `FortranConverter` function should use `setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)`.

What were you trying to accomplish with `nargs=0`?  Actions like 'store_true' use that to indicated that they don't take any arguments.  Otherwise it isn't a useful value for the programmer.

Comment: Simply putting `'-2.0'` worked, contrary to `'-2.0d0'` because there is no type conflict. The `nargs=0` thing was because I read too fast a question related to custom actions (with no arguments indeed).